# Time Series/Longitudinal Survival Analysis in R- is this possible?

Tags: r, time-series, survival, recurrent-events

Wondering if it possible to incorporate time series/longitudinal data into a survival analysis. I have data that represents different cases over a span of 5 years, with the same data gathered during each of the 5 years. After each year survival is recorded along with other measures that were repeated every year.

The data looks something like this, but with quite a few more explanatory variables.  There are also a few variables that are static such as the year they were initially diagnosed. (yr1-yr5 represent whether they were alive after year 1-5 [2 represents censored data points]; yrs is how many years since they were originally diagnosed; cv1-cv5 represent how many times they came into the clinic during each year 1-5; grp1-5 represent which treatment they had each year- this is something that could change but usually did not)

```
id yr1 yr2 yr3 yr4 yr5  yrs  cv1 cv2 cv3 cv4 cv5 grp1 grp2 grp3 grp4 grp5
1   1   1   1   1   1    7    2   0   4   0   1   400  400  400  400  400            
2   2   2   2   1   0    2                3   5                  300  300 
3   2   1   1   1   1    4    4   0   0   0   0        200  200  100  100 
4   1   1   0   2   2    9    3   1   0           200  200  200
etc.
```

The goal is to use survivor analysis to forecast death events by identifying patterns over the years leading up to the death event.

I've already read through quite a few websites dealing with survival analysis or recurrent events, a few are linked below, but haven't found any that discuss if/how to use time series or longitudinal data in a survival analysis. I would be grateful for any suggestions or resources you can direct me to.

https://www.emilyzabor.com/tutorials/survival_analysis_in_r_tutorial.html
https://rviews.rstudio.com/2017/09/25/survival-analysis-with-r/
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4339761/

Comment: Hi. Welcome to cross-validated. This is an interesting question. Can you clarify what is the data that is actually available?